# My smoke is not animating at all

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, shaders, keyframes, smoke-simulation

I'm trying to learn how to animate smoke and I found this nice [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li3sL7gbXY0). I tried to apply the tecnique to my specific situation. Infact I've created a 2D animation with a man that brings his hand/lighter to the mouth/cigarette and he lights it up. Towards the [end](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li3sL7gbXY0&t=191s) of the tutorial,the author wants to animate the smoke. Go to minute [7:52](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li3sL7gbXY0&t=472s) to see what he does. It seems that he puts a keyframe at frame 1 of the timeline and the rotation values on the mapping tab on the node editor become yellow. I did the same,but in my case the X values inside the mapping tab did not become yellow. Now go to the minute [8.19](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li3sL7gbXY0&t=499s) and you will see that he skips to frame 250 and he changes the X rotation value on the mapping tab to `-130.4` and then he puts another keyframe there. This is the [result](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=li3sL7gbXY0&t=550s) that he gets. His smoke is moving. But I don't get the same result. In my case the smoke texture remains the same ! So,there is something that does not work in my scenario. [Here](https://youtu.be/XlQadW3gQlA) you can see what I did. So,where I did something wrong ?

Comment: I understand that is a bit of work to use this site tools to share files, and add some image (taken from the video), but I'm sure you understand that if you delete the files from gdrive, and the video is removed, this question (and the answers) becomes pretty useless for anyone else, in the future... and if you also add shaping text and phrases in a slightly more readable manner, it would surely help people to follow you (and help) better... and future readers to learn from your experience, which is the real nature of this place.

Comment: no, you missed my point entirely...

Comment: why are you telling this ? I moved some file from my google drive to youtube,so that no-one can remove those files.

Comment: let me see an example of how I should make the next post,so that I can understand how to do it better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the adding of the keyframe - what it appears that you are doing is moving the mouse up into the 3D View and pressing <kbd>I</kbd>. This is adding a keyframe to the selected object in the scene. What you should actually be doing is hovering the mouse over the rotation value in the Mapping node (the value you just changed) and pressing <kbd>I</kbd> - this will set the keyframe on the node value (and make it turn yellow) so that it becomes animated.

Comment: thanks man,it was so easy but I haven't been able to understand it before.